# Automapper failing while mapping generic IEnumerable to generic List

Tags: c#, wcf, fluent-nhibernate, automapper

I did search in SO + google for mentioned problem, I went through all SO questions but did not get the solution of my issue.

Here is my problem: I am getting **AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException** while tried to map *IEnumerable prop with List prop*.

Here is snippet:

```
//Logical
public class TestClassPLogical
{
    public List<TestClassLogical> TestProp
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class TestClassLogical
{
    //defined prop
}

//Model

public class TestClassPDto
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<TestClassDto> TestProp
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class TestClassDto
{
    //defined prop
}

//Mapping

public class TestClassMapper
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        //ToDto
        Mapper.CreateMap<TestClassPDto, TestClassPLogical>()
             .ForMember(d => d.TestProp,
             o => o.MapFrom(s => AutoMapperExtensions.MapIEnumerableToList(s.TestProp)));

        //ToLogical
        Mapper.CreateMap<TestClassPLogical, TestClassPDto>()
            .ForMember(d => d.TestProp, o => o.MapFrom(s => AutoMapperExtensions.MapListToIEnumerable(s.TestProp)));

    }
}

//Custom class

public class CustomMapperExtensions
{
    public static List<T> MapIEnumerableToList<T>(IEnumerable<T> source) where T : class
    {
        return source == null
            ? new List<T>()
            : source.ToList();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> MapListToIEnumerable<T>(List<T> source) where T : class
    {
        return source.Count > 0
            ? source.ToList()
            : new List<T>();
    }
}

//Unit Test

public class TestClassMapperTest
{
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        TestClassMapper.Configure();
    }

    [Test]
    public void EnsureFieldsAreAllMappedOrIgnored()
    {
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

**P.S.**: We are using Fluent Nhibernate as ORM.

**Following is the exception:**

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException : The following property
>   on TestClassPLogical cannot be mapped:    **TestProp** Add a
>   custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify
>   the destination type TestClassLogical.

Any help to resolve above issue will be heartily appreciated.

**Update**
I already tried with ReverseMap(), which is throwing same exception, here is snippet:

```
//Mapping

public class TestClassMapper
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        //ToDto
        Mapper.CreateMap<TestClassPDto, TestClassPLogical>()
             .ForMember(d => d.TestProp,
             o => o.MapFrom(s => AutoMapperExtensions.MapIEnumerableToList(s.TestProp)));

        Mapper.CreateMap<TestClassDto, TestClassLogical>().ReverseMap();

        //ToLogical
        Mapper.CreateMap<TestClassPLogical, TestClassPDto>()
            .ForMember(d => d.TestProp, o => o.MapFrom(s => AutoMapperExtensions.MapListToIEnumerable(s.TestProp)));

        Mapper.CreateMap<TestClassLogical, TestClassDto>().Reverse();

    }
}
```

**Exception is:**

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException :  The following property
>   on TestClassPLogical cannot be mapped:
>
> **TestProp**
>
> Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or
>   modify the destination type TestClassLogical. Context:    Mapping to
>   property TestProp from TestClassDto to TestClassLogical   Mapping to
>   property TestProp from
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[TestClassDto, TestMapper,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] to
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[TestClassLogical, TestMapper,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] Mapping from
>   type TestClassPDto to ClassPLogical Exception of type
>   'AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException' was thrown.    at
>   AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.DryRunTypeMap(ICollection`1 typeMapsChecked, ResolutionContext context)
>   at
>   AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.DryRunTypeMap(ICollection`1 typeMapsChecked, ResolutionContext context)
>   at
>   AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.DryRunTypeMap(ICollection`1 typeMapsChecked, ResolutionContext context)
>   at
>   AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.AssertConfigurationIsValid(IEnumerable`1 typeMaps)
>   at AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.AssertConfigurationIsValid()    at
>   AutoMapper.Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I drill-down my code, also after knowing what does 'ReverseMap()' do exactly.

I have Mapped *TestClass* as:

```
public class TestClassMapper
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        //ToDto
        Mapper.CreateMap<TestClassDto, TestClassPLogical>();

        //ToLogical
        Mapper.CreateMap<TestClassLogical, TestClassDto>();
    }
}
```

Now, whenever I was trying 'ReverseMap()' as suggested by @Gert Arnold, it called mapping twice, one is with ReverseMap and another is with Configure() method and this broke everything.

**P.S.:** I have many child classes like

```
TestClassPLogical 
TestClassLogical 
TestClass1Logical 
TestClass2Logical
TestClass3Logical
```

Here is my changed snippet:

```
public class TestClassPMapper
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        //ToDto
        Mapper.CreateMap<TestClassPDto, TestClassPLogical>();

        //ToLogical
        Mapper.CreateMap<TestClassPLogical, TestClassPDto>();

        //What I changed
        TestClassMapper.Configure();

    }
}
```

Following code is working, when I removed `Configure()` method and make a call as follow:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TestClassPDto, TestClassPLogical>().ReverseMap()
Mapper.CreateMap<TestClassDto, TestClassLogical>().ReverseMap()
```

**P.S.**

- With above changes now, there is no need to Map prop even it is of
  Generic IEnumerable <=> List.
- I need have to use `.MapFrom()` only for those members/props, which required some kind of customization, like I need to map `Full_Name`, which should be `First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name`.

Finally, my unit test passed :)

```
public class TestClassMapperTest
{
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        TestClassMapper.Configure();
    }

    [Test]
    public void EnsureFieldsAreAllMappedOrIgnored()
    {
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

Comment: What you say after "Also found that following code is working:", isn't that what I told you?

Comment: @GertArnold - you are right, thats why I marked your answer +1. Reason to give answer of my own question is to describe my actual problem of code and I think it will be beneficial for others. Hope you agree with me. If you wann I can mark your post as answered but it actually did not solve my issue, however it helped me to drill-down the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You're making this much harder than necessary. Just map all class pairs you need and AutoMapper will be able to map nested source collections to nested target collections.

See this little example in Linqpad (I used some less confusing names):

```
void Main()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Parent,ParentDto>().ReverseMap();
    Mapper.CreateMap<Child,ChildDto>().ReverseMap();
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

    var par = new Parent { TestProp = new List<Child> 
                           { new Child(),
                             new Child() 
                           }
                         };
    Mapper.Map<ParentDto>(par).Dump();
    Mapper.Map<Parent>(Mapper.Map<ParentDto>(par)).Dump();
}

class Parent
{
    public List<Child> TestProp{ get; set; }
}
class Child {}

class ParentDto
{
    public IEnumerable<ChildDto> TestProp{ get; set; }
}
class ChildDto {}
```

Output of the `Dump` statements:

```
ParentDto
 - ChildDto 
 - ChildDto 

Parent
 - Child 
 - Child
```

Comment: Gert - I already tried the same, I am suspecting the issue with prop of IEnumerable. Updated description, please revisit and suggest.

Comment: Did you read the whole answer?  You don't need these extensions.

Comment: I read your words! I tried without mapping those properties having extensions and received an exception of unmapped members, I also tried without extension received above error. It is working fine if I marked these properties as Ignored.

Comment: OK, then you just didn't map *all* properties, but the quintessence is that you don't have to help  AutoMapper to map nested collections.

Comment: Yes, I wann to map all. All props are having same name and type, the only diff. for this prop is that one is having Generic IEnumerable and other one is List, if I did not map this one, received an unmapped exception, if mapped with or without extensions, received above exception. it only works if I mark it as ignore.

Comment: Then I don't understand why my example works. Which AM version do you have? My example is 3.2.1.

Comment: I figured-it out. Appreciated your help